# How to add external js file into Laravel project app.js file?

Tags: javascript, node.js, laravel, webpack

I want to use [this](https://github.com/alinawaz254/equalizer) package for audio equalizing animation. I want to add it in my Laravel project so I copied two files which are

```
jquery.reverseorder.js
jquery.equalizer.js
```

to `/myproject/node_modules/myjss/`

and added these two lines

```
import 'myjss/jquery.equalizer'
import 'myjss/jquery.reverseorder'
```

into `/myproject/resources/js/app.js`

but it returns `TypeError: $(...).equalizer is not a function`

How can I fix it?

Comment: Sounds like those files expect jQuery to be loaded globally as `$`.

Comment: They have already loaded and when I use `$('body').css('display', 'none');` it works and nothing shows then. So jQuery is working.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to save those files like that. Just save them in laravel's assets folder. then in laravel, you should include it like this `<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.reverseorder.js"></script>` . in src path, you can use asset_path of laravel. You can include this path in js or laravel's blade template.

Comment: Although in my Laravel version I don't have any assets folder but anyways I had done what you said and include it in the page separately from `app.js` but again it returned another error which was `SyntaxError: expected expression, got '<'`. But I think even if it didn't throw an error it is wrong way. Because it could be loaded within that `app.js` file but now three files should be loaded so the performance is less now I guess.

Comment: The way I told you is used by the creator of this plugin. make sure to load jquery script first, then those two files below it. then below all of these includes, write the usage of this plugin. it will work. 

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.reverseorder.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.equalizer.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#song').equalizer();
});
</script>

Comment: Yeah it is working when in an single html file with those three lines of includes but as I said it doesn't work in Laravel and it returns error `SyntaxError: expected expression, got '<'`.

Comment: Of course. When I add these two lines into my template file `    <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/jquery.reverseorder.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/jquery.equalizer.js"></script>` it will return `SyntaxError: expected expression, got '<'` and when I remove it and add these two lines into `app.js` file `import 'myjss/jquery.equalizer';
import 'myjss/jquery.reverseorder';` it will return `TypeError: $(...).equalizer is not a function`